# Class concept (a class accessing property then accessing method)

Tags: vb.net

I have a class called Car:

```
Public Class Car
    Public theColor As Color

    Public speed As Double
    Public Function run()
        Return speed
    End Function
End Class
```

In another class I create an instance of Car Class:

```
Public Class SUV
    Dim newCar As New Car

    Private Sub setColor()
        'set theColor property
        newCar.theColor = Color.Red

        Dim dgv As New DataGridView
        dgv.Rows.Add()

    End Sub

    Private Sub testDrive()
        'call run() function
        newCar.run()
    End Sub
End Class
```

From the code above, 
If I want to set a property of a class I just write an instance and the property:

```
newCar.theColor = Color.Red
```

Also if I want to call a method of a class I just write an instance then call the function or sub:

```
newCar.run()
```

But I dont understand how can a line of code be like this, for example:

```
Dim dgv As New DataGridView

dgv.Rows.Add()
```

The code above show that an instance `dgv` call property `Rows` than call a method `Add()`

Back to my class (the Car And SUV)
How to write the code in my class if i want to call the method like this?

```
newCar.theColor.resetColor()
```

And another code:

```
newCar.theColor.setColor() = Color.Red
```

I am sorry if the question's title isnt match with what i've asked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
Dim dgv As New DataGridView

dgv.Rows.Add()
```

is simply a more succinct equivalent of this:

```
Dim dgv As New DataGridView

Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows

rows.Add()
```

So, this code:

```
newCar.theColor.resetColor()
```

would be equivalent to this:

```
Dim theColor As Color = newCar.theColor

theColor.resetColor()
```

Now, how does that code make sense, given that the Color type doesn't have a method named `resetColor`?  What you're asking for is not possible because it doesn't make sense.  Resetting the colour is an action you perform on the `Car` object, not on the colour of the `Car` object.  How is doing something to the car the responsibility of the colour?

Comment: thanks for your reply

Actually i am not focusing on how to reset or change the color of the car obeject. I just want to know how can a code can be like : dgv.Rows.Add(). After the Rows property then we call the Add Function. the code you give is clear  enough

Dim dgv As New DataGridView

Dim rows As DataGridViewRowCollection = dgv.Rows

rows.Add()

But I want to do the similiar thing, how can we build a class that the instance of the object can call a property than call a method like this : dgv.Rows.Add()

Comment: You seem to think that there's some magic here that isn't. You don't have to do anything. You can already do that to EVERY property of EVERY class. A property returns an object and you can then access any member of that object. As I demonstrated with `DataGridView.Rows`, it doesn't matter whether you access that member directly from the property access or you assign the property value to a variable and then access the member from that. It's still the same object so you're still accessing the same member either way. Just define a class and declare a property and you have what you want.